# What is this Javascript function parameter doing?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Consider the following code (shortened for clarity):

```
Vertices.chamfer = function(vertices, radius, quality, qualityMin, qualityMax) {
    radius = radius || [8];

    if (!radius.length)
    radius = [radius];
};
```

I'm reading the first part as (pseudocode):

```
if (radius array passed to function) then
  radius = radius
else
  radius = [8] // new array, single element of value 8
end if
```

but I don't get the second expression (the `if(!radius.length) radius = [radius]` part).

Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm reading the first part as (pseudocode):
>
> `if (radius array passed to function) then`

`radius = radius || [8]` checks to see if `radius` is **falsy**, which might be not passed in at all (`undefined`), or passed in as `undefined`, or passed in as `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, or of course `false`.

But yes, it's probably intended to use `[8]` if no `radius` was specified.

> but I don't get the second expression (the if(!radius.length) radius = [radius] part).

If `radius` was given but is either A) An array with no entries (`radius.length` is 0 and therefore falsy), or B) Not an array (`radius.length` is `undefined` and therefore falsy), we create an array and make it the first entry in that array.

That's not at all robust validation, lots of things have `length` (strings, for instance), but that's probably what it's *meant* to do.

The robust way to check if something is an array is to use [`Array.isArray`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.isarray), which was added in ES5 and which can be reliably shimmed/polyfilled for obsolete engines (like the one in IE8).

Answer (score 1):

```
    Vertices.chamfer = function(vertices, radius, quality, qualityMin, qualityMax) {
            // Set the radius to the value passed in. 
            // If the value passed in is undefined, set the radius to an
            // array containing 8 (the "default")
            radius = radius || [8];

            // If radius isn't an array (i.e. length is 0 which evaluates to false), 
            // make it an array.
            if (!radius.length)
            radius = [radius];
        };
```

Comment: ...and keep in mind it will break if you pass the radius as a string, for example `"7".length == 1` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The concept used here is known as *[duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)* - i.e. checking the type of a variable by looking for the presence (or absence) of some characteristic properties/methods. Author of this code assumed that if something has a `length` property it is an Array, and if not it can be converted to an Array by wrapping it in `[]`.

The second part, converting `x` to a single-item Array containing `x` using `x = [x]` is totally OK.

The problem is there are other types in JavaScript that have a `length` so this test is not really reliable.

For example: `"7".length` returns `1`, so if you passed the variable as a string instead of a number (easy enough to make this mistake for example by reading values from `<input>` fields) something would break down the line expecting an Array but getting a String.

Another type that has a `length` is a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length): `(function(a,b){}).length == 2`.

So yeah, this is not really good test but the basic idea makes sense. Should have used either [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) or some other property/method that is unique to Arrays.

EDIT: I'd also point out the `radius = radius || [8]` construct is only OK if `0` is not allowed as the `radius` argument.

Comment: Beaten to the post but upvoted as an equally thorough answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if imported radius is not an array and it has value, then it returns an array with the radius value inside.

if imported radius is empty then it returns an array with the number 8 inside: [8]

However, inside the pseudocode, it is not gonna get in if statement, if the imported radius is not an array.